# Ugly radialGradient in Firefox. How I can fix it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm drawing a radial gradient sector with canvas. Chome works fine, Firefox produced weird and inconsistent results, different on different angles. How do I fix this?

```js
var options = {
  x0: 300,
  y0: 300,
  radius: 181,
  direction: 77,
  sight: 80
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function toRadians(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function drawSector(ctx, opt) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(options.x0, options.y0);
  ctx.arc(options.x0, options.y0, options.radius, toRadians(options.direction - options.sight / 2), toRadians(options.direction + options.sight / 2));
  ctx.lineTo(options.x0, options.y0);
  ctx.closePath();

  var grad_x0 = options.x0 + options.radius * Math.cos(toRadians(options.direction));
  var grad_y0 = options.y0 + options.radius * Math.sin(toRadians(options.direction));

  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(grad_x0, grad_y0, options.radius, options.x0, options.y0, 0);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.8, '#2287B9FF');
  // gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(92,141,255,0.2)');

  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

  ctx.fill();
}

drawSector(ctx);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700" style="outline: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Arris/s2qvsd73/

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me, Firefox 56.0.2.

Comment: works fine in Mobile FF 57.0, in chrome... empty viewbox in FF 43.

Comment: I remember a similar issue in an older version of Firefox, though: something similar occurs if too many lines are drawn too closely together; [it looked something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIXKd.png). I don’t think there’s anything you can do about it…

Comment: Why would you still be using FF 43? That's ancient.

Comment: FF43 supports tiddlywiki :) Latest versions does not support it :(

Anyway, my main browser is FF55 now.

Comment: Nope.
I update my FF to 57.0 (64-bit)

Same issue. Ugly canvas.

Comment: This is clearly a bug in Firefox (incl. v58). Consider [reporting it to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) (there doesn't seem to be any report on this at this moment).

Comment: @K3N and OP, if you decide to open an issue (which would be good), note that this is most probably a platform specific issue: I can not reproduce on FF 57~58 on osX and Android.

Comment: @Kaiido / OP: I have reported this as a bug. It can be found [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421139).

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to an error converting the coordinates of the gradient from double to float and can be fixed by forcing the radial gradient coordinates to be Int32s

Bitwise or with 0 will convert from JS Number to Int32 (signed integer 32bits) and fix the problem.

```
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    grad_x0 | 0, 
    grad_y0 | 0, 
    options.radius | 0, 
    options.x0 | 0, 
    options.y0 | 0, 
    0
);
```